# Rights & roles(RBAC) using express backend and passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm looking for a RBAC package or an exemple using middleware on express router.

I want to have various roles like admin, manager and user, set up at registration and checked at each request to the back end.

I have found few packages but never with the exact match for my situation and always about poorly stared/illustrated projects on GitHub(which is my reference to use an external package since I don't have enough experiences to be confident enough to use an unsupported package )

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [permission](https://www.npmjs.com/package/permission) package , its express and passport compatible.

Comment: Author asked for a RBAC implementation and not ACL.